# AngularJS - retrieving evaluated attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got the basic form input directive that sets up some form elements base on name:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('formInput', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^form',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, form) {
      var input, name;
      input = element[0].querySelector('input, textarea, select');
      name = input.getAttribute('name');
      // ...
      // do stuff with input, name, form etc.
    }
  };
});
```

In my HTML I do some simple DOM setup and it does the trick.

```
<div form-input>
  <input type="text" name="myElement"/>
</div>
```

The problem comes when I start having dynamic names, i.e.

```
<div form-input>
  <input type="text" name="{{ getDynamicName(element) }}"/>
</div>
```

The dynamic name is not evaluated prior to getting into my directive.  Is there a way to tackle this issue?

P.S. Given the decorative nature of the directive I prefer not to use isolate scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$timeout` service with 0ms to run code after the inner elements are linked:

```
// Note that $timeout is now injected to the directive
    angular.module('myApp', []).directive('formInput', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            //require: '^form',
            link: function (scope, element, attributes, form) {
                $timeout(function() {
                        var input, name;
                        input = element[0].querySelector('input, textarea, select');
                        name = input.getAttribute('name');
                        alert(name);
                }, 0);
                // ...
                // do stuff with input, name, form etc.
            }
        };
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20195/)